# Database error after transferring Drupal 6 site

Tags: 6, database

I just moved a Drupal 6 site from one server to another and have just started getting an error.

```
Warning: Table 'mydatabase.watchdog' doesn't exist.
```

The table does exist in the database and it does have the proper data in it. Some content does show up so the connection information is correct. Does anyone have any suggestions for this error? I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the table isn't corrupted or locked in some way. phpmyadmin should show you this when you view the list of tables in the database.

Try dropping the table and re-importing just that table, not the entire DB.